# How to connect with iPhone 5s in Xcode 14.3?

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-5

My MacBook is running macOS Ventura 13.4.1. I stopped my research after receiving information that my Xcode version does not support my phone version. But I thought maybe there is a solution and wanted to ask. The iPhone 5s is running iOS 12.5.7.

**Error Page**

[image: error page]

Comment: I am using iphone 5s and I want to see the application I made live on my phone, how should I go about it?

Comment: Use TestFlight. See my answer below.

Comment: First check your AppleId

Comment: Should be fine with xCode 14 which support from iOS 11. Be sure your iPhone is usin iOS 11 or 12. Also be sure to register your iPhone on Apple dev center.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run directly from Xcode to your phone. But you can certainly run your built app on your phone to see how it looks and behaves!

First make sure your deployment target is low enough. Then just use Xcode to archive your app and upload to TestFlight, and then use TestFlight app on your phone to download that build.

If that doesn't work for you, you could do an ad hoc build instead. But TestFlight is  simpler because you don't need to configure any special provisioning.

Comment: thanks for your comment matt but i faced the requirement that my ios version should be 14 and above to download testflight app on app store my phone version is 12

Comment: Then do an ad hoc build.